# Open Xcode Project in windows

Tags: ios, xcode, windows

I have developed my application for **iPad on Mac Desktop** and now I have to show the complete project to someone. Unfortunately I don't have **MAC Notebook**, I have only a laptop with **Windows OS**. How can I open and view my Xcode project on Windows in the same manner as in Xcode?

Note: I don't want to **compile or debug** my project, all I want is to open and **view the project** in a editor which gives me some basic feature like syntax highlighting and **organized source code and resources**.

Comment: In case you are expecting a better answer , you can be sure that there is ABSOLUTELY NO way to open an XCode project in Windows. You can either install a virtual machine as suggested or connect remotely to your MAC. (I am not sure to whom you need to show the code , but using a Hackintosh machine could be considered completely unprofessional..)

Comment: Wait wait. Its a school project and you need to show it to your professor? If yes , why would it even be your fault to not have a device to show the project? And something last. Why is it a problem to have both devices connected? If you have internet at home , then u just need to find any pc with internet to connect to it.

Comment: Still no answer satisfies your needs?

Comment: Yes i got one easy and only Solution: Borrowed a MacBook :)

Comment: too bad nobody suggested that :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run into this again, you can try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).  I just opened a folder that contained an xcode project and it opened them in the way you describe.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer! Sublime opens everything just fine

Answer (score 1):

Install [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) in both machines..

Log in to your MAC through TeamViewer and show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install virtual machine to achieve this . But this is really painful process since  there is large amount of the downloads and steps to follow . Go through the following link:
http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.in/2010/12/installing-ios-sdk-and-xcode-on-windows.html

But for just viewing  the project in the windows this is not a practical thing to do.

Comment: i already tried virtual Machine! its working though it is a very huge effort for very small task...